# No matching distribution found for pybullet==2.7.3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.7, pybullet

I am trying to install pybullet with Python3.7.9 as `python3.7 -m pip install pybullet==2.7.3`. I keep getting an error that says it can't find the version and as you can see from the full error below that the version is skipped in the error output.

However, PyPI seems to have the [release](https://pypi.org/project/pybullet/2.7.3/) of the package I am looking for.

Why is pip unable to find this version?

Full Error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pybullet==2.7.3 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.2.8, 1.2.9, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.2.9, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4, 2.5.5, 2.5.6, 2.5.7, 2.5.8, 2.5.9, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.6.6, 2.6.7, 2.6.8, 2.6.9, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.7.7, 2.7.8, 2.7.9, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.8.5, 2.8.6, 2.8.7, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.3, 2.9.4, 2.9.5, 2.9.6, 2.9.8, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.4, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.1.0, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.1.8, 3.1.9, 3.2.0, 3.2.2)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pybullet==2.7.3

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: My OS is: MacOS 12.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the version exists, if you look at the [files tab](https://pypi.org/project/pybullet/2.7.3/#files) you will see that for that version only whl files for `manylinux` are available. Interestingly, for most over versions (all the ones listed in your error output), an additional source distribution (`.tar.gz`) is available, just not for that version, so it cannot be installed on MacOS from pypi.

The releases on [github](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/releases) only go back to 2.86, so at this point it looks like you will have to pick one of the versions listed in your error message instead of `2.7.3`

Comment: I did use 2.7.4 and it worked. Thank you for the response!