# How to fix ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-quantum

Tags: python, installation, pip, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-quantum

when i'm trying to install tensorflow-quantum in Colab

```
pip install tensorflow-quantum==0.7.2
```

i got this error all the time, even after changing the version of python, and all solution given in Internet and nothing changed

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-quantum==0.7.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-quantum==0.7.2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install tensorflow-quantum using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74207230/unable-to-install-tensorflow-quantum-using-pip)

Comment: Welcome. okay, but you have not told what version(s) of Python you have tried.

Comment: ...and what OS you are working on. This https://stackoverflow.com/q/71834369/12846804 is not your solution but helps understand the error message. `from versions: none` seems to indicate there is no available versions at all for your system

Comment: Try ading `-v` to your command to get more information, as in [PyPi help Why am I getting "No matching distribution found" or "Could not fetch URL" errors during pip install?](https://pypi.org/help/#tls-deprecation)